# Converting multipage application to single page

Tags: javascript, html, television

I am building a TV application for Hbbtv, which works on the TV browser.

However now in my application, each page is specified in using anchor tag and every page loads when I click on a navigation menu.

How do I make this as a single page application as making the main page stay and only load the contents when I choose the menu options.
I program works on key press

so this is how my javascript looks like

```
function keyFunction(e) {
switch(e) {
    case "OK":
        switch(menuPosition) {
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "<h2>Welcome to HbbTV Tutorials</h2>";
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "<h2> Internet </h2>";
                break;
```

Each page has a lot of image and contents, so I don't think I can make use of inner HTML

Comment: You need a javascript library like react or angular

Comment: isnt there any other workaround

Comment: You can create SPA without any framework, it's just more work as you need to handle url change (routing) and write your code to display different "views" etc.

Comment: What is the server side code? Is there any web api on the back off the UI?

Comment: @Goran.it is correct, you dont **need** a framework... but without one you are going to be doing a lot of extra work.

Comment: is there a way i can put all the contents of a page in a div and replace divs as i click on the menu option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at JQuery and AJAX.
Storing your HTML pages and get the content through AJAX requests fired by user clicks.

This might help you : https://ilovecoding.org/courses/jquery/lessons/ajax-create-a-single-page-app-with-jquery

Comment: the tv doesnt support ajax

Comment: Well you could still do it with jQuery only and use the template tag : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: I’ts like switching divs as you asked in the comments above.

Comment: but i am not knowing how do i switch divs on key press

Comment: suppose there is home and about tabs. when i press ok on home how do i get the home div displayed

Comment: You could do the same as on the examples here : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp

Comment: To handle multiple templates, you could assign an id to all of them to get the right one when you need it. Like here :https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-reusable-markup-with-the-html-template-element